# PHP Apostrophe and query string

Tags: php, mysql

I want to supply a SQL statement from the query string, but all my efforts result in escaped single quotes and slashes.

Comment: Please show us your code, your input and your output.

Comment: If I'm reading your question correctly, then I would *strongly* advise against taking a SQL query in a query string.

Comment: yep, besides that you should never do that... work with actions... sorta like ?action=del => switch $action case: del => query

Comment: I'm creating a generic php webservice. It's basically a wrapper for mysql. This is not a good idea?

Comment: It's a hideous idea. Why would you want to wrap MySQL in a webservice? What's the use case?

Comment: So that I can access it from a Silverlight client.

Comment: If this is not a good idea, then how can I implement this in a generic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you really really want to do that. This is ripe for an SQL Injection attack.

If you want something to run statements against the MySQL database, just use phpMyAdmin or MySQL workbench.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using mysql, use mysql_real_escape_string()

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

> how can I implement this in a generic
>   way?

All queries must be hardcoded in your script.
Of course some of them can be dynamically built, but you're allowed to make only DATA dynamic, not control structures.
So, it must be like this:

```
$name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
if ($id = intval($_POST['id'])) { 
  $query="UPDATE table SET name='$name' WHERE id=$id"; 
} else { 
  $query="INSERT INTO table SET name='$name'"; 
}
```

or this:

```
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $query="SELECT * FROM table";  
} else {
  $id = intval($_GET['id'];
  $query="SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$id";  
}
```

or whatever.
Of course, inserted data must be properly escaped, cast or [binded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299182/prepared-parameterized-query-with-pdo).

But sometimes we need to use dynamic operator or identifier. The principle is the same: everything must be hardcoded in your script, nothing to be passed from the client side to the SQL query directly.
Say, to make a dynamic sorting, you can use a code like this

```
$orders=array("name","price","qty");
$key=array_search($_GET['sort'],$orders));
$orderby=$orders[$key];
$query="SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY $orderby";
```

or to assemble a dynamic WHERE:

```
$w=array();
if (!empty($_GET['rooms'])) $w[]="rooms='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['rooms'])."'";
if (!empty($_GET['space'])) $w[]="space='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['space'])."'";
if (!empty($_GET['max_price'])) $w[]="price < '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['max_price'])."'";


if (count($w)) $where="WHERE ".implode(' AND ',$w); else $where='';
$query="select * from table $where";
```