# Record is not showing if i use = instead of like '%$variable%' for mysql_query()

Tags: php, mysql

Well, in my user profile page i'm trying to get user record from db by following mysql query. but it's not working :

**Mysql Query (Not Working) :**

```
$sql =  mysql_query("select fname, email, find from users where email = '$username'");
```

but it's working fine:

**Mysql Query (Working) :**

```
$sql =  mysql_query("select fname, email, find from users where email = '%$username%'");
```

why ?

Ok, if you said % is ok then I've another problem that is I've to update the user profile page so that i'm using following mysql query :

```
UPDATE users SET fname = '$uname', find = '$find' WHERE email LIKE '%$username%'
```

BUT after run this query it's update all the db table rows.

What should i do know ? what is the correct mysql_query?

Comment: You are obsolete to sql injection.Dont use mysql_* functions.Use pdo or mysqli_*. Also never trust on user inputs.check what is in `$username`.

Comment: What is the value of `$username`, and what is in the actual table?

Comment: @웃웃웃웃웃 It's a email address.

Comment: @Barmar value of $username is email address and the actual table name is user "users"

Comment: check wether any space is comming with that variable.Use `trim()` or necessary functions if needed

Comment: @Alex Of course it's an email address, I'm not stupid. But obviously it's not the same email address as in the database. What is the actual value of it.

Comment: The reason LIKE works and = does not is because $username does not match any email in your user table exactly,  an email in there contains $username.

Comment: I didn't ask what the name of the table is, I asked what is _in_ the table? What email is being returned when you get the successful query with `LIKE`?

Comment: Run the query in phpMyAdmin using `=` and if it works then you know it's a problem with `$username`

Comment: @Alex Imagine if I post this: `uname=foo&find=bar&username=' OR 1 = 1--`. Suddenly all your users have their first name set to `foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is also a right sql by used only for when we fetch the data

```
$sql =  mysql_query("select fname, email, find from users where email = '%$username%'");
```

Like(% %)   $username= 'manish'
   when you search like email  '%$username%'" 
then it will return all where email have "manish" string

like

manish@yahoo.com
manishpatel@yahoo.com
yahoo@manish.com``

but when you update any data with the condition then is a sensitive so use sql like
Rigt SQL for Working when we update the data

```
 UPDATE users SET fname = '$uname', find = '$find' WHERE email = '".$username."'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change from :

```
$sql =  mysql_query("select fname, email, find from users where email = '$username'");
```

to

```
$sql =  mysql_query("select fname, email, find from users where email = ".$username);
```

Comment: You'll need quotes around the `$username`, not taking into account the huge sql injection problems you should be avoiding (and could be by using parameterised queries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299182/prepared-parameterized-query-with-pdo)