# string creation for mysql INSERT from $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Im using javascript ajax to post a value to PHP.
In this case, its an object of `{x: 5, y, 5}`

This will create a proper sql query which results in INSERT.

```
if (isset($_POST["item"])) {
    $var = $_POST["item"];
    $x = $var["x"];
    $y  = $var["y"];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO hex (id, x, y) VALUES (NULL, $x, $y)";
}
```

This however, will not work - at all. Why and how can it be fixed ? - thanks

```
if (isset($_POST["item"])) {
    $var = $_POST["item"];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO hex (id, x, y) VALUES (NULL, $var["x"], $var["y"])";
}
```

Will not work either:

```
if (isset($_POST["item"])) {
    $var = $_POST["item"];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO hex (id, x, y) VALUES (NULL, '$var["x"]', '$var["y"]')";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you use the " to create a String, and you use it to define your array variable. You cannot combine this. But you can do this to combine strings:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO hex (id, x, y) VALUES (NULL, '" . $var["x"] . "', '" . $var["y"] . "')";
```

*Note: that this is not a safe query since MySQL injection will be really easy. Please try to use PDO and parameters. See this answer:*

> [prepared parameterized query with PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299182/prepared-parameterized-query-with-pdo)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is caused becasuse of the double quotes.

Try this one:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO hex (id, x, y) VALUES (NULL, $var['x'], $var['y'])";
```

Or even this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO hex (id, x, y) VALUES (NULL, '.$x.', '.$y.')";
```